# Missing packages in private nuget feed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I'm trying to restore packages from a local nuget feed that was setup to prevent going to nuget.org for all the packages.

I can see all the packages in the visual studio UI when pointing at my private nuget feed. However in the browser view if I click "*Click here to view your packages*" I am only able to see 100 out of 231 that exist in the packages folder.

The error was evident following a Team city build that failed when it wasn't able to restore Nuget.Frameworks:

```
GET http://MyPrivateNuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='NuGet.Frameworks'
Unable to find package NuGet.Frameworks. No packages exist with this id in source(s): http://MyPrivateNuget/nuget
```

I have deleted all packages in my private nuget server except this one package:

[image]

And sure enough when I check in the browser it's empty:

[image]

But its in my Visual Studio "*Manage Nuget Packages*"

[image]

I have seen a few posts of issues where packages are in the feed but not in the Visual Studio UI, but this is the opposite. There is little to no information on this so I was wondering if I was missing a config setting or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that nuget.config at teamcity server provides your package source. (Or include nuget.config in your solution with pointing to private feed) 
And even if it does, please check that teamcity can reach this url.